# How to do MySQL Multi-insert from select statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

So here are the basics of my question. I have selected a result set from the join of two tables. This result set is a series of id values and email addresses. Now for each row in this result set, I want to insert a new row into a third table called `timestamps` that has a timestamp from `NOW()` and the id value from the result set, but not the email address. I know I can achieve this by running a loop within a stored procedure. Additionally I think I cannot simply run an `insert into` statement because the data I am inserting into `timestamps` does not come from my result set in its entirety, my result set data only decides the number of rows that must be inserted and the ids, while I need to return those email addresses for other processing. I am searching for a clever way to avoid using a loop for this. Is that possible? Can I generate a dynamic insert statement? Thank you to anyone who gives time or help.

Comment: Please give example of your tables. please specify with examples what are your exact requirements.

Comment: @krishnasahoo Oh wow. I do not remember. I will review my notes and question and try to reconstruct what I was up to back then, but this is still an unsolved issue, so thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

table1 with columns: id

table2 with columns: id, email

table1 and table2 are linked with column id

timestamps with columns: id, time

Then query will be:

insert into timestamps(id,time) select table1.id,now() from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;